# how to allocate the value of datetime type in sql mapper

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

When using mybatis I have a question about reading data which is selected into one given time interval. In the xml file, I write like:

```
<select id="getRecord" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultType="com.domain.record">
    select METHOD method, TIME_STAMP timeStamp 
    from RECORD 
    where TIME_STAMP BETWEEN #{startTime} AND #{endTime}
</select>
```

in another file, I write like this:

```
public List<Record> getRecord(String starttime, String endtime) {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    String startTime= "\'"+starttime + "\'";
    String endTime= "\'"+endtime + "\'";
    map.put("startTime",startTime);
    map.put("endTime", endTime);
    List<APIServerRecord> listRes=apiServerRecordMapper.getAPIServerRecord(map);
    return listRes;
}
```

It does not work. The size of `listRes` is zero and I'sure that there are many records and it should not be zero. And I'm sure that other sql statements in xml file is work. Meanwhile, if I give the time directly in xml file like the following code, it works:

```
 <select id="getRecord" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultType="com.domain.record">
      select METHOD method, TIME_STAMP timeStamp 
      from RECORD 
      where TIME_STAMP BETWEEN '2013-06-18 12:11' AND '2013-06-18 12:16'
</select>
```

Could you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to convert to the data type that MyBatis handled correctly (the handlers classes extend of `org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler`).

If the format of the string is the same, you can try:

```
private static DateFormat dateFormat =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

public static Timestamp convert(String str) {
    try {
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(str);
        return new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public List<Record> getRecord(String starttime, String endtime) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("startTime", convert(startTime));
    map.put("endTime", convert(endTime));
    List<APIServerRecord> listRes=apiServerRecordMapper.getAPIServerRecord(map);
    return listRes;
}
```